# Wordpress add get_template_part into shortcode php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a shortcode for my theme that will add a portfolio to a page/post. Because the code for the portfolio is quite long and complex, I have put it in a separate file and am trying to use get_template_part to call it from my shortcodes.php file.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
function portfolio_new($atts) 
{        
ob_start();  
get_template_part('/includes/shortcode_helpers/portfolio', 'shortcode');  
$ret = ob_get_contents();  
ob_end_clean();  
return $ret;    
}

add_shortcode('portfolio_new', 'portfolio_new');
```

However, this returns nothing. My file containing the portfolio php is located in incudes/shortcode_helpers/portfolio_shortcode.php

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your template file to `portfolio-shortcode.php` (with a dash rather than an underscore). get_template_part is checking for the following file:

`{current_theme}/includes/shortcode_helpers/portfolio-shortcode.php`

You also need to change the first parameter of get_template_part to remove the leading slash:

`get_template_part('includes/shortcode_helpers/portfolio', 'shortcode');`

See [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) on the WordPress Codex for the order of the files this function tries to include.